# it is hard to using tf.train.batch for np.array data

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np

xy = np.loadtxt('data-01-test-score.csv', delimiter = ',', dtype = np.float32)

# numpy array data is made for tensor 
x_imp_np = xy[:,:-1]
y_imp_np = xy[:,[-1]]

x_imp_ten = tf.constant(x_imp_np)
y_imp_ten = tf.constant(y_imp_np)


# make batches for data
x_batch, y_batch = tf.train.batch([x_imp_ten, y_imp_ten], batch_size = 10)



x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None,3])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None,1])

w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,1]), name = 'weight')
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]), name = 'bias')

hypothesis = tf.matmul(x,w) + b
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(hypothesis - y))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate = 1e-5)
train = optimizer.minimize(cost)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

x_data, y_data = sess.run([x_imp_ten,y_imp_ten])

for step in range(2001):
    x_batch_tr, y_batch_tr = sess.run([x_batch,y_batch])
    _, cost_val , hypothesis_val = sess.run([train, cost,hypothesis], feed_dict= {x: x_data, y: y_data})
    if step % 10 == 0:
        print(step, cost_val)
```

above code is just simple linear regression problem which is from sung kim's lecture. i have a problem about tf.train.batch. when queue was used, it operates well. however if i didn't uses the queue it doesn.t working. is there any method for not using queue data loading?

in here, it takes so much lots of time that it almostly useless..
i just want to use tf.train.batch for that numpy array by using just simple array slicing.